# How can I tell how long a missed call attempted to ring for?

Tags: iphone, call, spam

Sometimes autodialers call many numbers at the same time and direct the person (often a scammer or marketer) on the other end to whoever answers first. For this reason, I sometimes get missed calls where the caller only hangs on for 1-2 rings. When I see this, it's obvious that I can block that number. But when I view my phone and there are several calls from unrecognised local numbers in the missed calls list, I cannot find any way to differentiate between legitimate phone calls and the scammer calls. So if you were expecting an important call from an unrecognised number, there's a good chance you'll call back some scammers before you get the legitimate caller.

But there's a high likelihood that those calls that stopped after ~1 - 2 rings were scams and the ones that hung on for ~4+ rings were legitimate. The problem is, without seeing the attempted call in progress (to count the rings), I cannot differentiate the calls based on how many rings they hung on for.

For a missed call, without seeing it and counting, is there any way to tell how long the missed call attempted to call for (e.g. 1 ring, 5 rings, 10 rings etc)?

Comment: I don’t think there is a way.